# Shiny app with interactive bar chart and textInput

Tags: r, shiny, bar-chart, shiny-reactivity

I'm new to Shiny so am having troubles how the ui and the server talk to each other. I want to create a `ggplot2` bar chart with a dynamic filter argument, so I can enter a word in a `textInput` widget and so the bar chart changes.

### Data:

I'm working with abt 50,000 words from 300 docs, that's why I need an textInput but here's some example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

example_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~doc,         ~word, ~n,
   "A", "sustainable", 5L,
   "A",    "migrants", 2L,
   "A",    "building", 4L,
   "B", "sustainable", 2L,
   "B",    "together", 1L,
   "B",    "building", 5L
  )
```

### UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "word", 
                label = "Word:",
                value = "sustainable"),
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "barchart")
    )
  )
)
```

With this code I already bump into an error which I don't understand:

`Error in tag("form", list(...)) : argument is missing, with no default`

### Server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$barchart <- renderPlot({
    example_df %>%
      filter(word == input) %>%
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      head(20) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(doc, n),
                                     y = n)) +
      geom_col() +
      theme_minimal()
  })
}
```

I know this shiny code is probably crazy but all help is much appreciated!

Comment: There may be other issues but you have a comma after the `textInput() ` that is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two small errors:

firstly:

```
sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "word", 
                label = "Word:",
                value = "sustainable"),
    )
```

you just have an extra trailing comma which is not necessary and is why you are getting the error.

secondly:

```
example_df %>%
      filter(word == input)
```

You don't specify which input to use. The correct syntax is `filter(word == input$word)` where 'word' is your textInput's id.

The corrected code in full:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

example_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~doc,         ~word, ~n,
  "A", "sustainable", 5L,
  "A",    "migrants", 2L,
  "A",    "building", 4L,
  "B", "sustainable", 2L,
  "B",    "together", 1L,
  "B",    "building", 5L
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "word", 
                label = "Word:",
                value = "sustainable")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "barchart")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$barchart <- renderPlot({
    example_df %>%
      filter(word == input$word) %>%
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      head(20) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(doc, n),
                 y = n)) +
      geom_col() +
      theme_minimal()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```